# Unsupported operand type for /: 'str' and 'int'

Tags: python, roboflow

```
height, width, channels = img.shape

scale = ROBOFLOW_SIZE / max(height, width)

img = cv2.resize(img, (round(scale * width), round(scale * height)))
```

I've been trying to get a Roboflow code to work on my Picam but can't seem to bypass this error. I've defined ROBOFLOW_SIZE to be "416". Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please update your question with the code that defines `ROBOFLOW_SIZE`

Answer (score 2):

You cannot divide the `str`, `"416"` by an `int`.
It's like trying to divide the string, `"four hundred and sixteen" / 10`.

Convert it to an `int` first: `int(ROBOFLOW_SIZE) / max(height, width)`

Answer (score 0):

The answer from Kache is correct. Make sure `ROBOFLOW_SIZE` is the integer `416` and not the string `"416"`. If `ROBOFLOW_SIZE` is defined a `config.json` file, make sure the line with `ROBOFLOW_SIZE` looks like:

```
    "ROBOFLOW_SIZE": 416,
```

You can find a [sample config file here](https://github.com/roboflow-ai/roboflow-api-snippets/blob/main/Python/webcam/roboflow_config.sample.json).